# can a circle of infinite radius be possible??

Tags: geometry, circles, infinity

According to Ramanujan's infinity theorem, the infinity is -1/12. Then if we consider a circle of this -1/12 radius it has a negative area which makes no sense. But it is said that a circle with infinite radius is a straight infinite line???? How and what to believe??

Comment: This is just a jumble.  Even if you could somehow make sense out of a circle with negative radius, why would that mean it had negative area?  I expect that if you define your terms clearly, the answer will become clear or at least clearer.

Comment: There is no "Ramanujan's infinity theorem". There is no "the" infinity and it certainly isn't $-1/12$. What you may be thinking of is the sum of all natural numbers, but that also isn't $-1/12$ in any regular sense, but only in a very specific sense that requires a lot of theory to understand. A circle with negative radius is, depending on your conventions, undefined or the same as a regular circle with minus that radius and has positive area. A circle with infinite radius doesn't make sense per se. You can think of it as an analogy in some geometries, but not in Euclidean geometry.

Comment: The reason why the "equation" $$1+2+3+\cdots =-1/12$$ became famous is because it is totally absurd (it does not make a difference that it is true "in some sense" , in particular this "sense" is usually not mentioned), but many people think that they just cannot understand it, but that it must be right because "much more clever" people claim it. This was exactly how the relativity theories made their way. Don't believe such "sensations" without further researches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't have negative area. The set of all circles with radius $r\in\Bbb R$, let's denote this $C_r$, is given by:
$$C_r=\{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2|a,b\in\Bbb R\}$$

The area of any such circle is $\pi r^2$.

Its clear to see that $$\forall r\in \Bbb R; C_r\equiv C_{-r}$$

The greater problem with your question though is that $\infty=-\frac{1}{12}$ is not correct in any sense. It is the value of $\zeta(-1)$, but this isn't the same thing!

Comment: (+1) for answering both questions and mentioning the issue with the "equation"